# Graphing in Grafana a Philips Hue motion sensor json “last update” trouble

Tags: python, json, grafana, influxdb

I pull some json data from my Hue and get the sensors “last updated” as date and time and “presence” true / false. I have converted the date/time to unix time stamp and pushes this data to an influx database. How do I graph this as a “bit flow” chart? I need to connect the dots to the last time stamp because I only ask the sensor every 10 minutes.
Many thanks in advance!

I tried different grafana setups but didn’t get it to work.